# Basis for Witt algebra in general format

Tags: lie-algebras

The Witt algebra $W(n,m)$ is defined as the set of element ${∑f_jD_j such that f_j∈A(n,m)}$ with usual Lie bracket. I am a bit confused about basis for $W(n,m)$? What is the meaning of $"f_jD_j"$ ? I also know that $D_j$ is the partial derivation in $X_j$ on $A(n,m)$ and $A(n,m)$ is polynomial algebra. The set of ${X(a)D_i}$ for i between $1 and n$, and $a$ between $0$ and $p^(m_1)_−1,...,p^(m_n)−1$. Here p (prime number) is the characteristic of field.

Does This statement $"X^a Di"$ mean the i-th partial derivation of $X^a$? If so, why do not we write it $D(X^a)$? May you give me more details on the format of basis of Witt algebras? Need to say, I have already studied the book from Helmut Strade on Modular Simple lie algebras.
Lie bracket is defined for $W(n,m)$ as follows:
$$ [fD_i,gD_j]=fD_i(g)D_j-gD_j(f)D_i+fg[D_i,D_j]$$
I want to compute the above Lie bracket for example for elements of  $W(1,3)$ ? Please give me some notes.

Comment: I fear there's quite some undefined notation here...

Comment: How does this compare with the more typical definition in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt_algebra ?